# Do you need to install mongoDB locally to use Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This may be a dumb question but do you need to have mongoDB installed locally for mongoose to work in node? My database is hosted on a different server (mLab) than my web app so I'm not sure.

The documentation said to first install mongoDB and node but it was only used for testing purposes as far as I see and I was having some issues so wanted to make sure that wasn't the reason.

Makes sense now though!

Comment: where are you running your app for test purpose? I mean if you changed logic somewhere in your server code then where do you see the changed behavior?

Comment: No, you don't need to install MongoDB At all, mongoose just connect to any database URI you will give it whether it's locally or in the cloud

Comment: Can I suggest you re-word your question to show you have seen the documentation and find the documentation ambiguous and you want to know if it is referring only to localhost installs or remote as well, it may avoid the number of downvotes you are getting from people.

Comment: @Mohamed Hajr  Mongoose cannot connect with other databases other than Mongodb.

Comment: @EyoelD absolutely, "Any MongoDB URI" I put it in the wrong way.

Comment: @Mohamed Hajr Okay, I agree with you, as long as his uri points to his database, he should be good.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. I edited the question. Like the answer below said, I was mainly confused because the documentation said to first install mongoDB. I was having issues connecting to a remote mongoDB and didn't know if maybe not having mongo installed on the server with my web app was the result or not. Now I see that it wasn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I understand the confusion as the first line in the installation instructions for Mongoose says:

> First install node.js and mongodb. Then:
>
> ```
>     $ npm install mongoose
> ```

So it is fair to imply you need to install it.

However, given Mongoose wraps the mongodb native driver and that does not require MongoDB installation, I would expect that you do not need to have it installed when not using localhost.

That said, in my opinion it is worth installing anyway as you will most likely want to use the shell for accessing your instances for other configuration, data manipulation or testing purposes.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly why I was confused and what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see at the official site: 
"First be sure you have MongoDB and Node.js installed."

Comment: This is why I asked the question in the first place. I saw this in the documentation but in reality you do not need to actually have MongoDB installed so I was confused.

Comment: For those who have confusion. Mongoose used us ODM. So in case you are running locally you should install MongoDB. Otherwise you should supply the MongoDB host ip address.  you can read more here  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose